# How to implement textinput control and identification

Tags: database, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder, mxml

I have a text input box where users can add text, however I would like my program to identify the text in the box and match it up with text in a database.

So the user essentially can't add any text which isn't on the database. So the user will type in the text input box and maybe like a quick selection box appears below it to identify what is being added based on the items on the database.

Not sure where to start implementing this.

Textboxes are just normal textinput components at the moment:

```
<s:TextInput id="searchInput3" includeIn="AddingInput3" x="126" y="304"change="onChange3(event)"/>
```

Database is just a local xml file

Comment: How is the XML file loaded? what is the content of onChange3(event)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you meant auto completion in your text input.

You must search for this in your favorite search engine: "flex text input auto complete" and you should get many results.

One such example for the same is:

http://www.packtpub.com/article/building-a-flex-type-ahead-text-input